# How to return different types via a singleton instance method

Tags: java

How can i return another class instance in my class contractor ?
my pseudo code is :

```
class test
{
    private test() {}

    public static test getInstance() 
    {
        if(Condition)
        {
            return new otherClass();
        }
        else
        {
            return new test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return new OtherClass();`

Comment: you have to change return type of your getInstance method, on different line, why would you do that?

Comment: with your codes, `otherClass` must be subclass of `test`

Comment: I want to it because i need use overriding system in my app , for example for each client i have a special class.

Comment: make `otherClass` (or `OtherClass` as @MarounMaroun suggested) `extend` your `test` class.

Comment: Most important: `otherClass` has to extend `test`.

Comment: Dude you seriously need to learn about OOP concepts, specially about inheritance and polymorphism.

Comment: you can not override static methods

Comment: Why you are thinking i don know about oop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all: classes in java starts with an upper-case letter (by convention)

in general, a parent explicitly constructing its son is a bad practice but what you can do is get a factory that will construct it for you so the "son" wont be constructed by the parent.

the factory can be loaded from an outside source (props file ETC) or be given in the getInstance signature, in that case it wont have to be a member in the class.

note that the factory will have to be able to construct your class so it will have to be either a subclass of Test or in the same package, either way the constructor will have to be protected or you'll have to provide a method for construction in protected...

the below example shows 2 methods for that, in the 1st one the logic is in the "Test" class, in the other one the logic is in the factory, both have their cons and pros, I would go with the 1st as it encapsulate the logic in a more "correct" way...

```
class Test
{
    private TestFactory factory = null
    protected Test(...) {...}

    public static Test getInstance() 
    {
        if(Condition)
        {
            return factory.getOtherClass();
        }
        else
        {
            return factory.getTestClass();
        }
    }

    public static Test getInstance2() 
    {
       return factory.construct(Condition_Params);
    }
}

public abstract class TestFactory {

    public static Test getTestClass(){
        return new Test();
    }

    public static Test getOtherClass(){
        return new OtherTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: The factory class extended from Test class?

Comment: see an edit that I've just made - it can either be a sub-class or it can be in the same package - either way Test's CTor will have to be protected or it should provide a protected method for construction

Comment: I think i can not know it , i need to real example :( can you help me please

Comment: what help do you need?

Comment: i think my solution is not good for good app.true?can you please insert the factory class code in your reply?Very thanks for your cooperation

Comment: Thanks,why we have not access to OtherTest() class methods?

Comment: I have some question about this solution , can i use this solution for static methods?should i use this solution for declaring similar methods on different classes?(same name)

Comment: I dont think I got your intention...

if the methods are private no one can access it but the class itself, hence if the CTor is private only the class itself can access it and create an instance.

the reason for making them protected is that either a deriving class or a class in the same package will be able to access these members/methods so if you set the CTor protected you'll be able to construct it in the factory as long as it derives from it and/or relays in the same package.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of your `getInstance()` method has to reflect the common type of all the class types you can return i.e. it's going to be a *supertype* or a *common interface* shared by all those classes.

e.g.

```
public Vehicle getInstance() {
   if (...) {
     return new Car();
   }
   else {
     return new Bus();
    }
}
```

So in the above, both `Car` and `Bus` would derive from `Vehicle` (`Vehicle` could be a superclass or an interface). Otherwise the contract between the method return type and what is being returned would be violated. Note that you can choose any super type in the inheritance hierarchy - anything that is common to both (if you return an `Object` or something similarly simplistic you can't usefully work with the object without casting it, and that's a sign that something's not right in your design)

Your calling code will simply expect and receive a `Vehicle` (and not care whether it's a `Car` or a `Bus`)

```
   Vehicle v = Factory.getInstance();
    v.turnIgnitionOn();
    v.drive();
```

See [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-3-liskov-substitution-interface-segregation-principles--net-36710) for more info. Usefully, it uses the same `Vehicle` abstraction as I detailed above.

Comment: Can you explain more details?

Comment: what about `public Object getInstance()`? ofc you have to check the type of that object afterwards.

Comment: You may consider returning an interface instead of an object , therefore implemantation of intrface can be done in different classes for different cases.

Comment: Add the interface in your answer so that it is clear.